# progress bar loading not showing response from server?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-progressbar, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing news app but TopHeadlinesFragment loading progress bar not showing response from server
what I want to know where I am making mistake what I have to do in order to show response from server. Maybe something wrong with my observer in topHeadlinesFragment.kt or koin network module

below my screenshot of the app

[loading progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLwzV.jpg)

below my TopHeadlinesFragment.kt

```
class TopHeadlinesFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentTopHeadlinesBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModel<MainViewModel>()


    private lateinit var topHeadlinesAdapter: TopHeadlinesAdapter
    // private val newsRepository: NewsRepository by inject()


    //3
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_top_headlines, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        topHeadlinesAdapter = TopHeadlinesAdapter()
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initViewModel()
      //  loadingAds()


    }

    private fun initViewModel() {
        viewModel.sportList.observe(this, Observer { result ->

            when (result) {
                is Results.Success -> {
                    val newList = result.data
                    if (newList != null) {
                        topHeadlinesAdapter.updateData(newList)
                    }
                    binding.recyclerView.adapter = topHeadlinesAdapter
                    topHeadlinesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    viewModel.showLoading.observe(this, Observer {showLoading ->
                        pb.visibility = if (showLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
                    })
                }
                is Results.Failure -> {
                    viewModel.showLoading.observe(this, Observer {showLoading ->
                        pb.visibility = if (showLoading) View.INVISIBLE else View.GONE
                })
            }


        }

        viewModel.loadNews()
    })



    }


    }
```

below NewsRepository.kt

```
class NewsRepository(
    private val sportNewsApi: SportNewsInterface,
    private val sportNewsDao: SportNewsDao
) {


    companion object{
        const val  TAG=  "Error"
    }

    val data = sportNewsDao.getAllData()

    suspend fun refresh() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val articles = sportNewsApi.getNewsAsync().body()?.articles
        if (articles != null) {
            sportNewsDao.addAll(articles)
          Log.e(TAG,"Error")
            Results.Success(articles)
        } else {
            Results.Failure("MyError")
        }
    }
}
```

below My MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainViewModel(val newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
    val job = Job()

    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

    private val _showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val _sportList = MutableLiveData<Results>()

    val showLoading: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _showLoading

    val sportList: LiveData<Results>
        get() = _sportList


    fun loadNews() {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        _showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result =  newsRepository.refresh()
            _sportList.value = result
            _showLoading.value = false
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        job.cancel()
    }

}
```

below my KoinNetworkModule.kt

```
const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"
val netModule = module {


    single {
        createWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = BASE_URL
        )
    }
}

/* Returns a custom OkHttpClient instance with interceptor. Used for building Retrofit service */
fun createHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    client.readTimeout(5 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return client.addInterceptor {
        val original = it.request()
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        val request = requestBuilder.method(original.method, original.body).build()
        return@addInterceptor it.proceed(request)
    }.build()
}

/* function to build our Retrofit service */
inline fun <reified T> createWebService(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    factory: CallAdapter.Factory, baseUrl: String
): T {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(factory)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
}
```

Comment: What about visibility of your recycler view? Is it given as always visible in the layout? Is your progress bar getting hidden after the response?

Comment: hi Antonio data not showing at all only progress bar loading I think  problem with response issue or in the repository or MainViewModel.kt what is your suggestion I have checked and put break point data coming there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed problem by changing my code followingly.

```
 private fun initViewModel() {
        viewModel.sportList.observe(this, Observer { result ->

            when (result) {
                is Results.Success -> {
                    val newList = result.data
                    if (newList != null) {
                        topHeadlinesAdapter.updateData(newList)
                    }
                    binding.recyclerView.adapter = topHeadlinesAdapter
                    topHeadlinesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        })

        viewModel.showLoading.observe(this, Observer { showLoading ->
            pb.visibility = if (showLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        })

        viewModel.loadNews()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got your Problem. If you seriously want to show the response, whatever you are getting use this code in the Retrofit Instance. The role of Intercepter is used to show the request and response at the Log level. You can findout the URL of API, Request and resonse in the Log window.

Now modify  KoinNetworkModule.kt like this

```
            const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"
            val netModule = module {


                single {
                    createWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
                        okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
                        factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
                        baseUrl = BASE_URL
                    )
                }
            }

            /* Returns a custom OkHttpClient instance with interceptor. Used for building Retrofit service */
            fun createHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val client1 = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // write timeout
            .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // read timeout

            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()

            /* function to build our Retrofit service */
            inline fun <reified T> createWebService(
                okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
                factory: CallAdapter.Factory, baseUrl: String
            ): T {



                val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(factory)
                    .client(client1)
                    .build()
                return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
            }
```

Comment: hi Pawen maybe you think my problem related to retrofit

Comment: I have used koin network modele there maybe you need maybe network class

Comment: Yes.In network class you have to use this.. @EdgarShvedskiy

Comment: Hi Pawen Soni, I have posted KoinNetworkModule can you check it

Comment: Now Please check my answer. You can use same code. Modified your code.

Comment: BasicAuthInterceptor(
                            AppConstants.AUTHENTICATE_USER_NAME, AppConstants.AUTHENTICATE_USER_PASSWORD
                        ) where you did get this do you have AppConstains.kt as well

Comment: Yes. For put all the constants. @EdgarShvedskiy

Comment: Appconstant just like username and password for API. You can remove that from your code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/seccomiro/85446c4849855615d1938133bce30738 for  BasicAuthInterceptor I found above link

Comment: It base on the API. For API security purposes.

Comment: I understand but if I remove there are asking parameters

Comment: username and passwords

Comment: in this line  .client(client1)

Comment: Check Update code and before clinet1 add variable intercepter.

Comment: .client(client1) I am still getting error in this line do you have telegram

Comment: Now check modified Code. Working fine. Otherwise issue with other code.